# How to send mail without including html in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send a mail through Laravel. here's my code:

sendMailable.php file inside mail folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('view.name');
    }
}
```

my controller code is :

```
$data= ['name'=>'sakal de boss'];
            Mail::send(['text'=>'mail'],$data, function($message){
            $message->to($to, 'sakal')->subject('ami mail korsi');
            $message->from($from,'sakal');
        });

        echo 'hey';
         }
```

view page:

```
<div>
    Hi, This is : {{ $name }}
</div>
```

there is no other tags in my view page but still i am getting html tags in mail.

here is mail which i am getting.

Mail output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your **.blade.php** file: (**View**)

`{!! $name !!}`

Instead of this :  (This will render your **HTML**)

`{{ $name }}`

Answer (score 2):

use `{!! $name !!}` OR  `<?= $name ?>`
instead of `{{ $name }}`

OR

```
Mail::send(['html.view', 'text.view'], $data, $callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

your first parameter 'text' will concider as plain mail so Try below one

```
Mail::send('email view name',$data, function($message){
            $message->to($to, 'sakal')->subject('ami mail korsi');
            $message->from($from,'sakal');
        });
```

or

```
Mail::send( ['html' => 'email view name'], $data, function($message){
                $message->to($to, 'sakal')->subject('ami mail korsi');
                $message->from($from,'sakal');
            });
```